# How to make Pug compile "mycoolpage.pug" into "mycoolpage/index.html"?

Tags: javascript, pug

I've been starting to work with Pug templates

Normally, Pug seems to emit an HTML file for each PUG file

```
mycoolpage.pug => mycoolpage.html
a/clintons.pug => a/clintons.html
```

For many of my pages, this is great

However, for some pages, I would rather emit a directory for each `.pug` file

```
mycoolpage.pug => mycoolpage/index.html
a/clintons.pug => a/clintons/index.html
```

How can I best achieve this?

I'm just hoping to make my URLs more aesthetically pleasing, of course

PS, I've been using pug via simple command line usage, `pug source -o dist`

Comment: I do realize I could just rename all my "mycoolpage.pug"'s to "mycoolpage/index.pug" -- but I am holding out for a slightly more elegant solution, I think

Comment: Why are you not using pug inside node/express?

Comment: @Graham — i was using the cli to generate a simple static site — however i have now ultimately switched to using pug within a node script to get the results i was looking for

Comment: Glad to hear it, that's definitely a better way to go.  Perhaps consider deleting this question or adding more details to it so we can answer it :)